# Uninitialized constant in Rails from Gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, watir, headless

I am fairly new to rails and am chasing my tail trying to get a Rails app to run on my server. Locally on my Mac, everything is working fine, however when I run it on the Ubuntu server, I'm getting a `NameError (uninitialized constant Api::V1::TestController::Headless)` error. I have updated bundler and the relevant gems as was suggested in other posts. I am certain that Headless is in my gem file, is up to date, and is install properly. I am using Headless in with Watir Webdriver. Any suggestions on what could be causing this error would be greatly appreciated.

Ruby Version: 2.2.3

The controller in question:

```
class Api::V1::TestController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :json

  def index
    respond_with "test controller"
  end

  def create

    event_submit(params[:json_event])

    respond_to do |format|
      if ( @log.present? )
        format.json { render text: "Log: " + @log }
      else
        format.json { render text: "Error, no log" }
      end
    end

  end

  def nul_check(param)
    param ||= "none"
    return param
  end


  def event_submit(params)

    @log = ""

    #initialize the log
    @log = ""
    #set the browser that we will use to chrome for testing
    #use headless
    headless = Headless.new
    headless.start

    browser = Watir::browser.start 'www.google.com'

    @log += browser.title

  end

end
```

The Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'


# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.2.4'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 5.0'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.1.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0', group: :doc

#Api gems
gem 'active_model_serializers'
gem 'deathbycaptcha'
gem 'rspec'
gem 'responders', '~> 2.0'


#Driver gems
gem 'watir-extensions-element-screenshot'
gem 'selenium-webdriver'
gem 'chromedriver-helper'
gem 'headless'
gem 'nokogiri'
gem 'watir-webdriver'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3'
  # Call 'byebug' anywhere in the code to stop execution and get a debugger console
  gem 'byebug'
end

group :development do
  # Access an IRB console on exception pages or by using <%= console %> in views
  gem 'web-console', '~> 2.0'

  # Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
  gem 'spring'
end


gem 'unicorn'
```

Comment: If instead of `Headless` you put `::Headless` (note the double colon), does it work?

Comment: Does putting `require 'headless'` at the top of the controller help?

Comment: using ::Headless has no noticeable effect. I get the same error.

adding `require 'headless'` to the top of the controller causes a gateway time out. It does not add anything to the error log, and it does not have any effect when i do it at local level. I am severing with Unicorn/Nginx

Comment: Shot in the dark, but is `Xvfb` installed as well?  The `headless` gem is a wrapper for `Xvfb`, which may not be installed on your ubuntu machine.

Comment: Xvfb is installed, and running a test .rb script for headless works 100% fine. even running the same code that is in the event_submit method as it's own .rb script with the proper requires works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be server ownership. The user, rails in my case, did not have ownership of the gems since I had run `bundle install` under my own account. A `chmod` for the rails user took care of the problem!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that Rails looks for the `Headless` constant under the `Api::V1::TestController` namespace.

You should use `::Headless` (kind of absolute path to constant).

Comment: I think Ruby should resolve the top-level constant `Headless` from within `Api::V1::TestController`. Perhaps there are differences in behavior between different Ruby implementations which I'm unaware of. Typically prefixing a constant is necessary only when the given constant name appears in more than one namespace and does not resolve to the desired instance from the current context.